# how to create permanent hadoop filesystem in hadoop 2.6.0

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

I am working on apache hadoop 2.6.0. Every time I start my system, I have to create a new filesystem. How can I create a permanent hadoop filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

this may be a solution:

You can use **hadoop snapshot mechanism**,

this [link](http://www.aosabook.org/en/hdfs.html):  "8.2.7. Upgrades and Filesystem Snapshots".